# How to change values dynamically in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, dynamic, chat

I am developing a basic chat functionality in Node.js. So , i have list of users list , by clicking on each index i can get the unique values , which will help me to do private Client-Server chatting. But i am not able to figure out how can i change the value in **app.js** file.

**Node.js code**

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
num = "1";

  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    
  server.listen(4000);

        app.get('/', function(req, res){
             //res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
             res.render(__dirname + '/index.html', { num: num });
       });

        io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

           socket.on('send message'+num, function(data){
               io.sockets.emit('new message'+num, data);
        }); 

 });
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
<div id="chat"></div>
<form id="send-message">
    <input size="35" id="message"></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        var socket = io.connect();

        var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
        var $messageBox = $('#message');
        var $chat = $('#chat');
        var msg = $('#message').val();
        var num = "1";

        $messageForm.submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            socket.emit('send message'+num, $messageBox.val());
            $messageBox.val('');
        });

        socket.on('new message'+num, function(data){
            $chat.append(data + "<br/>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: Property 'engine' of object #<View> is not a function
at View.render (C:\node_demo\chat\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:76:8)
at Function.app.render (C:\node_demo\chat\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:506:10)
at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\node_demo\chat\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:756:7)
at C:\node_demo\chat\app.js:16:6
at callbacks (C:\node_demo\chat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:161:37)
at param (C:\node_demo\chat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
at pass (C:\node_demo\chat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:142:5)
at Router._dispatch (C:\node_demo\chat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:170:5)
at Object.router (C:\node_demo\chat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
at next (C:\node_demo\chat\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
```

I can able to change the **"num"** variable dynamically in index.html but i cannot find out how can i do the same in **app.js** file. How can i pass the value to app.js file.

Please let me know , suggest me some good solution.

Comment: Not sure this is directly affecting your error, but as mentioned in your other post on the subject, using a dynamic event name is not a great idea. In your case, it's incredibly easy for your client and server to get out of sync on what the value of "num" currently is, and your socket event won't be handled on the server if it doesn't know what event the client is raising.

Answer (score 2):

Use templating. For [`ejs`](https://github.com/tj/ejs) you just need to:

- `npm install ejs`
- `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`
- Change `res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');` to `res.render(__dirname + '/index.html', { num: num });`
- Then in your `index.html` change `var num = "1";` to `var num = "<%= num %>";`

Comment: Yes i installed ejs but i am getting ReferenceError: num is not defined in app.js file

Comment: That's because you just commented it out in your code. You need to set `num` from *somewhere*, whether you get that information from the socket object or somewhere else is up to you. The important thing is to set the correct `num` in the object literal passed to `res.render()`.

Comment: Now i am getting TypeError: Property 'engine' of object #<View> is not a function